# Notify Comment owner when a reply Post is submitted laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have 3 tables users comments and post related as follows :

User.php

```
    // User Model
public function posts()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Post::class);
}

// User Model
public function comments()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Comment::class);
}
```

Post.php

```
    /**
 * Get the owner of the post
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\belongsTo
 */
public function user()
{
  return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}

/**
 * The has Many Relationship
 *
 * @var array
 */
public function comments()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Comment::class)->whereNull('parent_id');
}
```

Comment.php

```
    /**
 * The belongs to Relationship
 *
 * @var array
 */
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}

/**
 * The has Many Relationship
 *
 * @var array
 */
public function replies()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Comment::class, 'parent_id');
}
```

I am trying to create a notification .. when a user replies on a specific comment or owner post ...

so I created a new notification called RepliedToPost.php

```
    public function __construct($comments)
{
    $this->comments=$comments; 
}

/**
 * Get the notification's delivery channels.
 *
 * @param  mixed  $notifiable
 * @return array
 */
public function via($notifiable)
{
    return ['database'];
}

/**
 * Get the array representation of the notification.
 *
 * @param  mixed  $notifiable
 * @return array
 */
public function toArray($notifiable)
{
    return [
        'user_id' => $this->user['id'],
        'comment' => $this->body,
        'user' => $this->notifiable,
    ];
}
```

CommentsController.php

```
    public function store(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'body'=>'required',
    ]);

    $input = $request->all();
    $input['user_id'] = auth()->user()->id;

    $reply = Comment::create($input);
    auth()->user()->notify(new RepliedToPost($reply));


    return back();
}
```

Its work but the resulte is NULL .
i don't no what what am i doing wrong. Pleas Help

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'body'=>'required'
    ]);

    $input = $request->all();
    $body= $request->body;
    $user = User::find(auth()->user()->id);

    Comment::create($input);
    $user->notify(new RepliedToPost($body));


    return back();
}
```